# List items is not updating after deleting selected list in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I just started work with Angular, and it's pretty good to implement. Now I am trying to delete list items which are created dynamically. I am able to delete items, but the list items is not updating. I did Google but didn't get any solution.

Here is my `HTML` stuff

```
<li data-ng-repeat="category in user track by $index">
<div class="pull-left forDrop"><label class="customLabel" id={{category.id}}><a href="" class="viewBooks" ng-mousedown="viewAll(category.id)">{{category.category_name}}</a></label></div>
              <div class="pull-right actions">
                <a href="" class="trash secondry" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalOne" data-ng-click="getCatId($index,category.id)"></a>
                <a href="" class="pvtLock" ng-class="{'lock secondry':category.category_type===1,'openLock secondry':category.category_type===0}"></a>
                <a href="" class="done secondry" data-ng-mousedown="updateCategory()"></a>
                <a href="#" class="penEdit primery"></a>
              </div>
```

And this is the `controller method`

```
$scope.getCatId = function(index, category_id) {
    cat_id = category_id;
    cat_index = index;
     $scope.user.splice(cat_index,1);
  };
```

May be its wrong implementation, I don't know.

Please any suggestion will be helpful for me.

*Thank You.*

**Updated**

If I delete the items from bottom, then it updates list

Comment: Can you also put a console.log(cat_index), console.log($scope.user) immediately below the splice call? Need to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
 var res= $scope.user;
            // var index =cat_index;
              res.splice(cat_index,1);
              //$scope.user.hideColony= true;
              $scope.user= res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Wait, why are you calling $scope.user.push($scope.user.splice)? Just splice it. Change that line to:

```
$scope.user.splice(cat_index,1)
```

Try wrapping this code in $timeout as well (although you shouldn't need to):

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.user.splice(cat_index, 1);
});
```

And also inject $timeout where you injected $scope.

Comment: Can you post some more code and do console.log of $scope.user immediately after the splice statement?

Comment: Yes @Peter, I am getting all results except deleted item

Comment: One thing more if I delete from bottom, then it updates.

Comment: Try changing cat_index to just index, I'm worried you have some global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to call `$scope.$apply();` for the changes to take effect

```
$scope.getCatId = function(index, category_id) {
    cat_id = category_id;
    cat_index = index;
    $scope.user.push($scope.user.splice(cat_index,1));
    $scope.$apply()
  };
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Comment: This is not a good idea because a digest could already be running, and should be since ng-click should trigger one.